# Including static data in setup.py (setuptools)

Tags: python, setuptools

I am currently coding setup.py using setuptools.
And I want to copy the static data (which is not a Python module) to site-packages.

The thing is, the current folder hierarchy is structured like the following:

```
setup.py
src
    Pure Python Module
skeleton
    example
        __init__.py
    resources
        static
            error.css
            example.css
            logo_shadow.png
        template
            error.html
            example.html
    server.tmplt
```

I want to copy the skeleton directory to site-packages **WHILE maintaining the folder structure/hierarchy**, but how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by processing the static files separately, not using setuptools.

```
from sys import argv
try:
    if argv[1] == 'install':
        from os.path import join
        from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
        from shutil import copytree
        OrigSkeleton = join('src', 'skeleton')
        DestSkeleton = join(get_python_lib(), 'cumulus', 'skeleton')
        copytree(OrigSkeleton, DestSkeleton)

except IndexError: pass
```

Comment: It's better to use `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`, as it overwrites it if it's already there. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12686557/161801.