# How to copy directory recursively in python and overwrite all?

Tags: python, copy, distutils

I'm trying to copy `/home/myUser/dir1/` and all its contents (and their contents, etc.) to `/home/myuser/dir2/` in python. Furthermore, I want the copy to overwrite everything in `dir2/`.

It *looks* like `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree` might be the right tool for the job, but not sure if there's anything easier/more obvious to use for such a simple task.

If it is the right tool, how do I use it? According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html) there are 8 parameters that it takes. Do I have to pass all 8 are just `src`, `dst` and `update`, and if so, how (I'm brand new to Python).

If there's something out there that's better, can someone give me an example and point me in the right direction?

Comment: `os.system("cp -rf /src/dir /dest/dir")` would be pretty easy...

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley (+1) - however, according to `cp`'s docs, the `-f` arg ("force"): *if an existing destination file cannot be opened, remove it and try again*... this doesn't seem to be the same as "overwrite all". Can you confirm it is the same and that whatever `dir1`'s contents are all get (recrusively) copied to `dir2`'s subtree? Thanks again!

Comment: try it ... it should work fine :) ive never had a problem with it...

Comment: @4herpsand7derpsago: `cp` overwrites files by default. There's a switch that *prevents* it from overwriting files, but not the other way around.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Is that method platform independent?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### Notice:

`distutils` [has been deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils-deprecated). Consider looking for other answers at this question if you are looking for a post-3.12 solution.

---

### Original answer:

You can use [`distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree). It works just fine and you don't have to pass every argument, only `src` and `dst` are mandatory.

However in your case you can't use a similar tool like`shutil.copytree` because it behaves differently: as the destination directory must not exist this function can't be used for overwriting its contents.

If you want to use the `cp` tool as suggested in the question comments beware that using the `subprocess` module is currently the recommended way for spawning new processes as you can see in the [documentation of the os.system function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Comment: Thanks! Just a note, I needed two imports to get this to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908941/unable-to-import-distutils-dir-util-on-windows/33417555#33417555

Comment: This module some times has conflict with git files. For example, it cannot copy .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG files. Recommend shutil.copytree instead.

Comment: What is the logical/philosophical difference between `shutil` and `distutils.dir_util`? Is one preferable to the other in general?

Comment: distutils.dir_util.copy_tree doesn't overwrites exiting files

Comment: Found the solution, you need to set the preserve_mode=0, otherwise, it doesn't overwrite anything.

Comment: Also, beware that if you call this method twice with the same arguments it will fail if you cleaned the target directory: https://bugs.python.org/issue22132

Comment: Isn't `distutils` deprecated, or is that only in favour of `setuptools` in `setup.py`?

Comment: distutils.dir_util.copy_tree() works wonders if you want to avoid shutil.copytree's "cannot copy when file exists' issue.

Comment: As the documentation suggests, `shutil.copytree` now has `dirs_exist_ok` option. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree.

Answer (score 66):

Have a look at the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) package, especially [`rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) and [`copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree). You can check if a file / path exists with `os.paths.exists(<path>)`.

```
import shutil
import os

def copy_and_overwrite(from_path, to_path):
    if os.path.exists(to_path):
        shutil.rmtree(to_path)
    shutil.copytree(from_path, to_path)
```

Vincent was right about `copytree` not working, if dirs already exist. So `distutils` is the nicer version. Below is a fixed version of `shutil.copytree`. It's basically copied 1-1, except the first `os.makedirs()` put behind an if-else-construct:

```
import os
from shutil import *
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    names = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()

    if not os.path.isdir(dst): # This one line does the trick
        os.makedirs(dst)
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                # Will raise a SpecialFileError for unsupported file types
                copy2(srcname, dstname)
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except Error, err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
        except EnvironmentError, why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
    try:
        copystat(src, dst)
    except OSError, why:
        if WindowsError is not None and isinstance(why, WindowsError):
            # Copying file access times may fail on Windows
            pass
        else:
            errors.extend((src, dst, str(why)))
    if errors:
        raise Error, errors
```

Comment: Your example doesn't overwrite anything, simply replace one dir with another. Replacing content and overwriting content are different things as far as I know. The question specifically ask for overwriting.

Comment: Well, I guess that depends on your definition of overwrite. If you want to have non-duplicate files in the target folder preserved or not. This version is not preserving anything, true.

Comment: I just had a look into the code of `copytree`. So if you just want this plain overwrite as mentioned by @Vincent, you can simply use `shutil.copytree()` and you're done. Present files are automatically overwritten.

Comment: `shutil.copytree` shouldn't work; if it does, that's a bug, because its docs say "The destination directory, named by *dst*, must not already exist".

Comment: how to use ignore param, can you share an example?

Comment: This won't merge contents.

Comment: @sivann What WILL merge contents?

Answer (score 59):

In Python 3.8 the `dirs_exist_ok` keyword argument [was added](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#shutil.copytree) to `shutil.copytree()`:

> `dirs_exist_ok` dictates whether to raise an exception in case `dst` or any missing parent directory already exists.

So, the following will work in recent versions of Python, even if the destination directory already exists:

```
shutil.copytree(src, dest, dirs_exist_ok=True)  # 3.8+ only!
```

One major benefit is that it's more flexible than `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()`, as it takes additional arguments on files to ignore, etc. (see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#shutil.copytree)). On top of that, the accepted [PEP 632](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/) also states that `distutils` will be deprecated and subsequently removed in future versions of Python 3.

Answer (score 39):

Here's a simple solution to recursively overwrite a destination with a source, creating any necessary directories as it goes.  This does not handle symlinks, but it would be a simple extension (see answer by @Michael above).

```
def recursive_overwrite(src, dest, ignore=None):
    if os.path.isdir(src):
        if not os.path.isdir(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)
        files = os.listdir(src)
        if ignore is not None:
            ignored = ignore(src, files)
        else:
            ignored = set()
        for f in files:
            if f not in ignored:
                recursive_overwrite(os.path.join(src, f), 
                                    os.path.join(dest, f), 
                                    ignore)
    else:
        shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I like the fact that it doesn't remove existing files. I had to add a little piece to make sure that the destination directory exists for files in the `else:` part.

Comment: shouldn't it be `else: shutil.copyfile(src, dest, ignore)`?

Comment: This was the only function I found working when I have to do repetitive copying and deleting.

Comment: @JackJames No it shouldn't since `copyfile()` is only called for a single file. When using `ignore` then you pass a folder to `src` (since otherwise if you would ignore the file you are pass to `src` you would not have to call the function at all). When passing a folder, `copyfile()` will be never called for ignored files.

Comment: I replaced  `shutil.copyfile(src, dest)` with  `try:  copy2( src, dest )  except SameFileError: src.replace( dest )` to copyover the file meta data too.

Comment: Can you explain what is `if ignore is not None: ignored = ignore(src, files)`? Is ignore a function? But it has not been declared yet...

Comment: @SunBear The `ignore` parameter has exact same meaning as `shutil.copytree()`'s `ignore` parameter. The caller of recursive_overwrite provides an `ignore` callable, which will receive two parameters on callback: (1) a directory string, (2) all entries(file+dir) from that directory.

Answer (score 1):

My simple answer.

```
def get_files_tree(src="src_path"):
    req_files = []
    for r, d, files in os.walk(src):
        for file in files:
            src_file = os.path.join(r, file)
            src_file = src_file.replace('\\', '/')
            if src_file.endswith('.db'):
                continue
            req_files.append(src_file)

    return req_files
def copy_tree_force(src_path="",dest_path=""):
    """
    make sure that all the paths has correct slash characters.
    """
    for cf in get_files_tree(src=src_path):
        df= cf.replace(src_path, dest_path)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(df)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(df))
        shutil.copy2(cf, df)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about SYNC.

[How to synchronize two folders using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688687/how-to-synchronize-two-folders-using-python-script)

```
from dirsync import sync
source_path = '/Give/Source/Folder/Here'
target_path = '/Give/Target/Folder/Here'

sync(source_path, target_path, 'sync') #for syncing one way
sync(target_path, source_path, 'sync') #for syncing the opposite way
```