# Error, file already exists. Python

Tags: python, io, shutil

When I am using `shutil`, I get an unexpected error:

```
System error 183. Cannot create file when that file already exists
```

I am using this:

```
shutil.copytree(src,dst)
```

`src`,`dst` are paths to my directories which I would like to copy. Names are different. For example:

```
src = 'D:\test\tmp\dir1'
dst = 'D:\test\tmp\dir2'
```

I know, I could delete `dir2` and everything is ok, but I would like to do it without this, is it possible with `shutil` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy directory recursively in python and overwrite all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683834/how-to-copy-directory-recursively-in-python-and-overwrite-all)

Answer (score 0):

The document for shutil specifically says that the destination directory must not exist. This happens because it makes a os.makedirs(dst). If you want to append files it could be useful if you used shutil.copyfile.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if using shuthil is possible here. Perhaps you can save as a new file?