# what is important difference between using shutil.copytree() and cp -r <source> <destination> ?

Tags: python, cp, shutil

I know two methods of copying a directory recursively from source to destination. 
1) `cp -r <source> <destination>`
2) `shutil.copytree(<source>, <destination>)`

Method 1 is linux standard method. method 2 is  pythonic way of copying a directory by importing `shutil` module within a python script.

Can anyone explain me any significant/fundamental difference between working of the two ? Which one is faster ? Which one is safer ? Since i can run `cp -r` command from within python script by python's `os.system()` function, i want to know  which method should i use if i want to copy directories within a python script ?

Comment: What if your script using `os.system` is run on Windows? It definitely won't work, while `shutil` is cross-platform, just like Python itself.

Comment: `cp` is a binary from your linux distro. `shutil.copytree` is bunch of Python code.

Comment: good point @Forcebru.

Comment: Also wondering about this. the `copytree` page gives a bunch of warnings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html ; to the point where I think it's easier to just invoke a subprocess shell and copy things that way

Comment: Indeed, we can see here that spawning a new subprocess might be the better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683834/how-to-copy-directory-recursively-in-python-and-overwrite-all